# Search and Replace in Windows XAMPP site

Tags: database, mysql, localhost, xampp, windows

In my Ubuntu VPS, to search and replace in a DB of a site I do for example:

```
cd /var/www/html/example.com
sudo wp search-replace "http://" "https://" --all-tables
```

Yet in Windows 10 I use XAMPP and can't do this action with WSL + WP-CLI because one cannot use Bash inside windows (yet).

### My problem

I have installed a backup version of an online website in Windows XAMPP and all main menu links turn to the online site so I need to change in DB from `https://` to `localhost://`.

### My question

How could I easily and efficiently change the DB from `https://` to `localhost://`. in XAMPP in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the new database selected, then run some sql updates and replacement commands on the tables notably, wp_options, wp_posts, wp_postmeta.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'https://livesite.com', 'http://localhost/sitename') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'https://livesite.com','http://localhost/sitename');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'https://livesite.com', 'http://localhost/sitename');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'https://livesite.com', 'http://localhost/sitename');
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the Search Replace DB available here - https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

It has a great UI and also you can perform a "dry run" to see which tables will get affected before actually making any changes.